# What do I do if I use Google+ and GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm developing android app, and it is using Google+ and GoogleMap api.

Before changing google-play-services api, I use PlusClient and LocationClient. It was fine.

But, from February 2014, GoogleApiClient was created, it is recommended to use GoogleApiClient instead of subclass of GooglePlayServiceClient.

So, I tried to change to use GoogleApiClient. But There is nothing about changing LocationClient.

Even though I try to change PlusClient only, then my code becomes messy. Because GoogleApiClient and GooglePlayServiceClient must have their own interface (ConnectionCallbacks and OnConnectionFailedListener.)

What can I do to use GoogleApiClient for Google+ and GoogleMap?
Or, where can I find some hints for this?

Comment: I'm in the same situation. The [Location documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) is out of date and the [new documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html) doesn't outline anything for Location

Comment: I searched it again and again, but I cannot find the way. So, I changed activity flow to separate GoogleMap and Google+. Then, when user start the GoogleMap activity, app uses GoogleApiClient, otherwise, app uses GooglePlayServiceClient.